# SQL Date Condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to run a query that returns a set of results for dates less than today and do not include certain dates. For some reason my results include dates in the future (e.g. the year 2016, 2025, 2030, etc..).

What am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT DISTINCT
LTRIM(RTRIM(term_date)) as term_date
FROM [IMR].[PERSON].[vwIMRDetailMostRecent]
WHERE emp_description = 'active'
AND CONVERT(char(8),LTRIM(RTRIM(term_date)),1) < CONVERT(char(8),GETDATE(),1)
AND CONVERT(char(8),LTRIM(RTRIM(term_date)),1) <> '01/01/01'
AND CONVERT(char(8),LTRIM(RTRIM(term_date)),1) <> '01/01/00'
AND CONVERT(char(8),LTRIM(RTRIM(term_date)),1) <> ''
ORDER BY term_date desc
```

Comment: If term_date is a date / datetime column, then you can simply say "... AND term_date < GETDATE() ..." without having to use CONVERT.

Comment: Syntax looks very much sqlserver-ish, so I'm assuming that. Also, seeing as you also trim the term_date attribute, it probably isn't a datetime field. And if it doesn't return the right records, it probably isn't formated well. You could try how it responds to a convert to datetime.

Comment: Thank you HoneyBader that was the problem. Term_Date was of datatype varchar, when I converted it to datetime the results were correct based on my conditions. Thanks!

Comment: @BPurchell data type is column `term_date` ?

Answer (score 0):

Does this helps?

```
SELECT DISTINCT
(term_date)
FROM [IMR].[PERSON].[vwIMRDetailMostRecent]
WHERE emp_description = 'active'
AND (term_date) <> CONVERT (date, GETDATE())
AND (term_date) <> CONVERT (datetime,'01/01/01',101)
AND (term_date) <> CONVERT (datetime,'01/01/00',101)
AND (term_date) <>
ORDER BY term_date desc
```

For date formatting see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx